# Define an array with #define command not complying with misra rules

Tags: c++, arrays, c-preprocessor, misra

I have this definition:

```
static const char* STRING_ARRAY[NUM_UNITS] = STRING_ARRAY_VALUES;
```

when

```
#define STRING_ARRAY_VALUES                 \
{   "n/a",                                  \
  "bool",                                   \
  ...                                       \
}
```

Unfortunately, it's not complying with MISRA-C++ Rule 8-5-2:

```
"MISRA-C++ Rule 8-5-2 (required): Braces shall be used to indicate and match the 
structure in the non-zero initialization of arrays and structures."
```

Can anyone please explain to me why it's not complying? I thought that the #define command turn the definition to something like:

```
static const char* STRING_ARRAY[NUM_UNITS] = {"n/a", "bool",...}
```

which is complying with MISRA rules.

Is there a way to make this to comply with MISRA while keeping the `#define`?

Comment: Where is this declaration?

Comment: the array is in a .cpp file and the #define is in .h file.

Comment: Works fine for me if I take out the ellipsis, declare `NUM_UNITS`, and put it all in a cpp file.

Comment: what do you mean by "works fine"? it's working, but gives MISRA warning. And this is a big project and i can't move the #define into the .cpp file

Comment: I mean the only warning I get is for an unused variable in Clang and GCC, and no warnings in Intel. If you try it in a new project and don't get a warning, I'd wager we need to see an sscce that does.

Comment: @chris You have to run it through a MISRA-C++ compliant static analyser. If you have no idea what that is, then just forget you saw this question :)

Comment: @Lundin, Yeah, it took me a bit after that to figure that out, but even so, I can't imagine why it would give such an error. Your answer supports that in the fact that it gives no error for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible causes:

- Either your MISRA checker is broken. I tested your code with LDRA Testbed and it produces no errors.
- Or I suppose NUM_UNITS possibly does not match the number of pointers passed to the array. It is not clear to me whether this is a violation of the MISRA rule or not. You could add a static assert that `sizeof(STRING_ARRAY)/sizeof(const char*)` == `NUM_UNITS`, which is good practice to do regardless of MISRA.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. There was one comma missing in the define, so my guess is that instead of NUM_UNITS parameters there were NUM_UNITS-1 parameters. Although, I would have expected it to fail in the compilation stage because of the missing comma.

Comment: @or.nomore It wouldn't fail because two string literals, `"hello" "world"` written next to each other like in this example, or with a new line in the source code, will get automatically concatenated by the pre-processor into one item "helloworld". This is a language feature so that programmers needn't write excessively long strings in one single source line.

Comment: **I would have expected it to fail in the compilation stage** - No... it is legal, syntactic C/C++ albeit illogical - which is why the MISRA Rule exists!